# How can I call a function inside ngFor in Angular2

Tags: angular

I tried to call a function inside the *ngfor but it repeats data binding. How can I call a function inside ngfor loop

My View product.html

```
       <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let product of productlist">
            <ion-thumbnail item-left>
                <img src={{product.picturePath}}>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col width-60>
                        <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
                        <p>500 GM</p>
                        <p>$100</p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col width-40>

                        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
                        </button>     -->
                        <span item-right >GetProductQuanityByCustomer(product.id)</span>
                    </ion-col>

                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My product.component.ts file

```
GetProductQuanityByCustomer(productId:number)
{ 
    this._productservice.GetProductQuantityByCustomer( productId,122 ).subscribe( p=>this.productQuantity=p )
    return this.productQuantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I woul invoke it from code and assign to an variable in component.

```
productQuantity: number = 0;
.
.
.

productQuantity = GetProductQuanityByCustomer(number)
```

But according to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html. You can use expression:

```
{{GetProductQuanityByCustomer(product.id)}}
```